# Prove or disapprove that the integral converges using Taylor's series

Tags: integration

$\int_0^\infty\sin(\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt x})dx$

I have an idea to do smth like that:

$\int_0^\infty\sin(\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt x})dx = \int_0^\infty(\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt x} + O(\frac{1}{\sqrt x}))$ and this integral should converge, but I have a feeling that I did smth wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\int_0^\infty\sin\left(\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{x}}\right)\,dx=\int_0^{100}\sin\left(\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{x}}\right)\,dx+\int_{100}^\infty\sin\left(\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{x}}\right)\,dx.$$ The first integral is clearly finite since $\sin\left(\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{x}}\right)$ is bounded. For the second integral, note that $\left|\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{x}}\right|\leq\frac{1}{10}<1$, so we have $$\sin\left(\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{x}}\right)=\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}\right),$$ where $f(x)=O(g(x))$ means $|f(x)|\leq C|g(x)|$ for some positive constant $C$. This follows from the Taylor series expansion of $\sin x$. Thus, the integral on the right reduces to $$\int_{100}^\infty\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx+O\left(\int_{100}^\infty x^{-3/2}\,dx\right)=\int_{100}^\infty\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx+O(1).$$

The integral here converges by [Dirichlet's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test); putting it all together, we have that the original integral converges.

Comment: (+1) Since the main part of  the article you cite on Dirichlet's Test is devoted to sums, it might be useful to point to the [improper integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test#Improper_integrals) part of the article (instead).

Comment: Thanks, @robjohn :)

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\sin\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt x}+O\!\left(\frac{x^{3/2}}{1+x^3}\right)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sqrt{\frac\pi2}+O\!\left(\frac{2\pi}3\right)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Can you explain the big-Oh term after the first equality? I'm not sure I totally understand (of course, for large $x$, it's essentially the same as mine, I'm just curious how you approached the problem to get this form).

Comment: @Clayton: $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\le1\implies\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\le\sqrt{x}$ and $\sin(x)\le1\implies\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\le\frac1{\sqrt{x}}$. Taking harmonic means gives $\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\le\frac{2\sqrt{x}}{1+x}$ and thus, $\frac{\sin^3(x)}{x^{3/2}}\le\frac{8x^{3/2}}{(1+x)^3}\le\frac{8x^{3/2}}{1+x^3}=O\!\left(\frac{x^{3/2}}{1+x^3}\right)$. This combined with $\sin(x)=x+O\!\left(x^3\right)$ gives the estimate.

Comment: Thanks! I wouldn't have thought of using harmonic means. It's interesting for sure.